# I am getting a syntax error on this SQL script when trying to pull data via an ODBC and i'm not sure how/why

Tags: sql, odbc

I am running the following script but am encountering an error.  It is essentially the combination of two separate scripts. So I think one of the JOINs is off but not sure where.  I am pulling data from our ERP via an ODBC in winsql.

Also how would I add month to this?  Probably something simple like:

```
TO_CHAR(Month(t.TRANDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS CreatedMonth
```

The query which has got problem is:

```
SELECT
    t.TRANSACTION_TYPE AS TranType
    ,tl.ACCOUNT_ID AS AcctId
    ,a.NAME AS Account
    ,a.TYPE_NAME AS AcctType
    ,t.TRANSACTION_ID AS DCOGSTranId
    ,t.TRANID AS DCOGSNo
    ,TO_CHAR(t.TRANDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DCOGSCreateDt
    ,TO_CHAR(t.TRANDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS CDate
    ,t.CREATED_BY_ID AS DCOGSCreatedById
    ,tl.SUBSIDIARY_ID AS SubSidId
    ,ss.NAME AS SubSidiary
    ,tl.LOCATION_ID AS LocId
    ,t.ENTITY_ID AS CustomerId
    ,tl.ITEM_ID AS ItemId
    ,NVL(SUM(tl.GROSS_AMOUNT),0) AS DirectCOGS$
    ,NVL(SUM(tl.ITEM_COUNT),0) AS DirectCOGSQty
    ,ilm.ITEM_ID AS ItemId
    ,ss.NAME AS SubSidiary
    ,ilm.LOCATION_ID AS LocId
    ,TO_CHAR(ed.ExpireDt,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS ExpireDt
    ,TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS CDate
    ,NVL(ilm.AVERAGE_COST,0)*NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS AvgCost
    ,NVL(ilm.LAST_PURCHASE_PRICE,0)*NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS LastPurchPrice
    ,NVL(ilm.AVERAGE_COST,0) * NVL(ilm.ON_HAND_COUNT,0) AS OnHandCost$
    ,NVL(ilm.ON_HAND_COUNT,0) / NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS OnHandQty
    ,NVL(bin.BinOnHandQty,0) / NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS BinOnHandQty
    ,NVL(ilm.AVERAGE_COST,0) * (NVL(ilm.IN_TRANSIT_COUNT,0)) AS InTranCost$
    ,NVL(ilm.IN_TRANSIT_COUNT,0) / NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS InTranQty
    ,NVL(ilm.AVERAGE_COST,0) * (NVL(ilm.AVAILABLE_COUNT,0)) AS AvailCost$
    ,NVL(ilm.AVAILABLE_COUNT,0) / NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS AvailQty
    ,NVL(bin.BinAvailQty,0) / NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS BinAvailQty
    ,NVL(ilm.AVERAGE_COST,0) * (NVL(ilm.ON_ORDER_COUNT,0)) AS OnOrderCost$
    ,NVL(ilm.ON_ORDER_COUNT,0) / NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS OnOrderQty
    ,NVL(ilm.AVERAGE_COST,0) * (NVL(ilm.QUANTITYBACKORDERED,0)) AS BackOrdrdCost$
    ,NVL(ilm.QUANTITYBACKORDERED,0) / NVL(u.CONVERSION_RATE,1) AS BackOrdrdQty  
FROM TRANSACTIONS t
JOIN TRANSACTION_LINES tl ON t.TRANSACTION_ID = tl.TRANSACTION_ID
LEFT JOIN ITEMS i ON tl.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS t2 ON t.CREATED_FROM_ID = t2.TRANSACTION_ID
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS a ON tl.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
LEFT JOIN SUBSIDIARIES ss ON tl.SUBSIDIARY_ID = ss.SUBSIDIARY_ID
WHERE tl.ACCOUNT_ID = 128
FULL OUTER JOIN ITEM_LOCATION_MAP ilm ON tl.ITEM_ID = ilm.ITEM_ID
JOIN ITEMS i ON ilm.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN UOM u ON i.PURCHASE_UNIT_ID = u.UOM_ID
LEFT JOIN PRIMARY_SUBSIDIARYS_MAP psm ON ilm.ITEM_ID = psm.ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN SUBSIDIARIES ss ON psm.SUBSIDIARY_ID = ss.SUBSIDIARY_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ITEM_ID, LOCATION_ID, MIN(EXPIRATION_DATE) AS ExpireDt FROM INVENTORY_NUMBER
    WHERE EXPIRATION_DATE IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID, LOCATION_ID) ed ON ilm.ITEM_ID = ed.ITEM_ID AND 
    ilm.LOCATION_ID = ed.LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ITEM_ID, LOCATION_ID, SUM(ON_HAND_COUNT) AS BinOnHandQty, 
    SUM(AVAILABLE_COUNT) AS BinAvailQty
    FROM BIN_NUMBER_COUNTS
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID, LOCATION_ID) bin ON ilm.ITEM_ID = bin.ITEM_ID AND 
    ilm.LOCATION_ID = bin.LOCATION_ID
    WHERE (ilm.ON_HAND_COUNT != 0 OR ilm.IN_TRANSIT_COUNT != 0 OR 
    ilm.ON_ORDER_COUNT != 0 OR ilm.QUANTITYBACKORDERED != 0)
GROUP BY
    t.TRANSACTION_TYPE
    ,tl.ACCOUNT_ID
    ,a.NAME
    ,a.TYPE_NAME
    ,t.TRANSACTION_ID
    ,t.TRANID
    ,t.TRANDATE
    ,t.CREATED_BY_ID
    ,tl.SUBSIDIARY_ID
    ,ss.NAME
    ,tl.LOCATION_ID
    ,t.ENTITY_ID
    ,tl.ITEM_ID
```

Comment: Please post your error too.

Answer (score 1):

Really should post what the error is to help us out...but

```
LEFT JOIN SUBSIDIARIES ss ON tl.SUBSIDIARY_ID = ss.SUBSIDIARY_ID
WHERE tl.ACCOUNT_ID = 128
FULL OUTER JOIN ITEM_LOCATION_MAP ilm ON tl.ITEM_ID = ilm.ITEM_ID
```

Replace WHERE with AND.

where is a separate clause and not part of the join statement.  you can use and key1 = key 1 and key 2 = key 2 and key 3 = 'hi'

Comment: Ahh okay thanks.  I am new to both SQL and Stack so I will take note of the protocol.  The error that it returned wasn't very informative hence the post.  It was simply: "SQL Syntax Error"